# Use USB port as serial comms to PC for STM32-NucleoF411 on Win10

Tags: usb, putty, serial-port

I have a STM32 Nucleo-F411RE that I am using with WIN 10, 64 bit.

I'm able to program it and everything OK.  But I want to be able to use the usb port that I use for debugging so that I can just connect something like putty and see program output without having to start a debug session.

Everything I see online talks about a virtual com port that is installed with ST Link, but There is nothing listed under PORTS in device manager.  The only thing that shows up is STM32 STLink under Universal Serial Bus devices, but I can't figure out if I can use this to connect.

Anyone know how I can do this?

I've been using OpenOCD to debug.. it uses localhost port 3333 to connect, but I can't connect to that through putty.

Comment: Your question is outside the help center of superuser. You are unlikely to find people here who have experience with your specific development environment. You should post this question to the board developer's forum https://community.st.com/s/

Comment: In order to connect via serial, a COM port is required AFAIK; while I can't offer insight into a vCOM port, have you considered an actual USB-to-TTL cable _(I always recommend [FTDI](https://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBTTLSerial.htm) as they're known to be the best)_, which registers as a COM port when plugged in? _(Many SBCs come with an onboard UART/serial support via the USB port, although I'm not familiar with the board you're working with.)_

Comment: Did you install the latest STLINK driver?
https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stsw-link009.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking to connect to the Virtual COM port of the ST-Link? In that case, some boards will not support a virtual comm port profile because the ST Link cannot be updated to the latest version.
Some newer boards that can be updated to the latest ST Link firmware will support a virtual COM port profile and show up as a COM port in your device manager, using which you can print debug logs.